# Complexity of $n \sqrt{n}$

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

I know that $O(n\sqrt{n}) = O(n)$ but I have no idea how I can prove this.
Can you give me a hint?

Comment: What is $*$ ???

Comment: Should be the multiplication symbol

Comment: This is not true...

Comment: * is a multiplication symbol in spreadsheets, Word formulas, and most computer languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to prove is actually not correct.

Obviously, $n\sqrt{n} \in O(n\sqrt{n})$, but

$$\frac{n\sqrt{n}}{n} = \sqrt{n}.$$

Since $\sqrt{n}$ is not bounded, we have $n\sqrt{n} \notin O(n)$.